# JavaScript RegExp method exec() returns only one item

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex exec only returning first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283071/regex-exec-only-returning-first-match)

```
"a1b2c3d".replace(/[0-9]/g,"x")
```

returns "axbxdxd" as expected.

```
/[0-9]/g.exec("a1b2c3d")
```

however only returns an array containing one item: ["1"]. Shouldn't it return all matches?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920038/regexp-exec-not-returning-global-results

Comment: ok, thanks, I didnt found that answer

Comment: @diaho: That's a markedly different question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You need to call `exec` multiple times:

```
var re = /[0-9]/g;
var input = "a1b2c3d";
var myArray;
while ((myArray = re.exec(input)) != null)
{
  var msg = "Found " + myArray[0] + ".  ";
  print(msg);
}
```

**Edit**: The [Mozilla Developer Network page on `exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) has much more to say about this function. That's where I got the example and modified it for your question.

**Edit 2**: I've changed the above code so it isn't actually an infinite loop. :-)

Comment: unfortunately the example posted by you doesn't work - its an infinite loop returning only "1". Any idea?

Comment: @muffel: Try moving the regex to its own variable? `var re = /[0-9]/g;`...and then use that in the `while` loop: `while ((myArray = re.exec("a1b2c3d")) != null)` ?

Comment: Well, that was neat. Running the posted code in Chrome generated an infinite loop of print page windows. Had to kill it and come back. :-) BTW, yes, put it in a variable first. Otherwise you're recreating a fresh regex each iteration.

Comment: I needed to move as well the regex as the string (?) to their own variables. Finally it works. Thank you!

Comment: @Wiseguy: fixed and fixed. :-)