# Why this regex isnt working?

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to split cookies into gropus using this regex `(.*?=.*?); ?`
What i meant to get is a cookie in each regex group.
But it's only giving me the first group that match.

```
var string = userid=edaa4200-b140-47fd-9db8-b48082a0d0a8; ab_93896527=0;
```

edit : I'm using `exec()` function

```
var cookies_tuples = /(.*?=.*?); ?/g.exec(string);
```

what could be the problem ?

Comment: How are you running it? `"userid=edaa4200-b140-47fd-9db8-b48082a0d0a8; ab_93896527=0;".match(/(.*?=.*?); ?/g)` returns the two goups.

Comment: WebStorm using nodejs, but even in Regexr.com i get this problem
i used the exec() function

Comment: How ==> some code... Or it's not a JavaScript question

Comment: Why not split with `;`?

Comment: you have to call `exec` multiple times. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9216715/244811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to call `exec` multiple times, even with the global flag enabled:

```js
    var re = /(.*?=.*?);\s?/g;
    var input = "userid=edaa4200-b140-47fd-9db8-b48082a0d0a8; ab_93896527=0;";
    var myArray;
    while ((myArray = re.exec(input)) != null)
    {
      var msg = "Found " + myArray[0];
      console.log(msg);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `string.match` method as indicated below. If you use `RegEx.exec` you'll need to iterate to get all the matches.

```js
var s = "userid=edaa4200-b140-47fd-9db8-b48082a0d0a8; ab_93896527=0;"
var cookies_tuples = s.match(/(.*?=.*?); ?/g);

console.log(cookies_tuples);
```

Answer (score 0):

in https://regex101.com/ it gives me both cookies. You havo to run it greedy <- with the g-flag

- and bevor anyone can complain, you need 50 Reputation to comment, so I just wrote an answer ;)

Comment: the `g` flag is for global, not to be confused with greedy `.*` vs non-greedy `.*?` tokens.

Comment: sorry, my bad - shitty memory help on my side ^^